# Blender object and armature jumps up from surface

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I am working on animation and I have an object and an armature. When I go from object to edit mode the object moves up above the surface. And when I go from edit to object it moves down. See images and mode.

Object Mode
[image]

Edit (move up from plane)
[image]

POse mode moves down same as object.
[image]

Comment: could you please share the armature? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>  on pose resets the position.